# Select columns ordered by latest creation date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having serious performance issues when running my query. Is there any other way of doing it in apart from using window function?

This is t1. I want to connect it to t2 and t3 in order to filter out specific field from another table. I want to extract id, newValue based on the latest creation date by update_at column:

```
id | newValue| update_at |
--------------------------
1  |   x     | 01-01-2022 
1  |   y     | 02-01-2022
1  |   z     | 03-01-2022
2  |   a     | 01-01-2022
2  |   b     | 02-01-2022
```

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT "id" ,"newValue"
FROM (
   SELECT f.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY f."id" ORDER BY f."updated_at" DESC) RN
   FROM "t1" AS f
   WHERE f."fieldName"='xyz'
) AS f
INNER JOIN "t2" as c
ON f."id" = c."id"
INNER JOIN "t3" as p
ON c."projectId"= p."id"
WHERE f.RN = 1 AND p."id"='s'
```

[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAeEU.png)

Comment: Hi, what is the problem with the window function? Is it performing poorly aswell? If so, please add the query plan (`explain (analyse, buffers)`)

Comment: The output of the query is taking a lot of time to complete. I tried putting query plan however I'm getting an error "ERROR: syntax error at or near "ANALYZE" Position: 46"

Comment: which client are you using? The following syntax has to work `EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: I am using cloud solution based on AWS when executing the query - QuickSight

Comment: ANALYZE isn't at position 46, so apparently you have munged different commands together, presumably by missing a semicolon.  I think RDS also provides a way to get query plans through their web GUI, but I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: What version is this on?

Comment: Why are your already randomly named tables given even more random aliases? Is "fieldName" supposed to be the same thing as "newValue"?

Comment: Version: I am not sure where to check this. I do not have administration view. "fieldName" is one column in the table which defines all the fields available. I want to extract data only for specific one so that's why i'm using WHERE clause. The table consists of millions of rows. Radnom alias -> They were added without sense, do not pay attention to them. In the original code, I have table names and alias assignments. Here I changed the names quickly, hence the mess.

Comment: I added picture to the original post of my sql query with EXPLAIN(ANALYSE,BUFFERS)